# useTestNG in gradle not picking dynamic suites being passed through project extention property

Tags: gradle

I have defined a test Task that uses the TestNG to run testcases and am passing a list of testNG suites file dynamically for it to run. However it does not seem to pick the file list dynamically.

```
task runTestNG(type: Test) {
doFirst {
if(project(':testNG').hasProperty("testJerseyFiles")) {
  ext.ngFiles = project.property("testJerseyFiles")
  List testFiles = ngFiles as List
  if(testFiles != null && testFiles.size() != 0 ) {
    println "++++++++If : runTestNG++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
    testFiles.each { test ->
      println "${test}"
    }
  }
} else {
  println "++++++++Else : runTestNG++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
}
}
useTestNG() {
if(project(':testNG').hasProperty("testJerseyFiles")) {
  ext.ngFiles = project.property("testJerseyFiles")
  List testFiles = ngFiles as List
    if(testFiles != null && testFiles.size() != 0 ) {
      listeners << 'org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter'
      ignoreFailures = true
      testFiles.each { test ->
        println "******* ${test}  ***************"
        suites new File ("${test}")
        //options.suites(new File ("${test}"))
      }
    }
  } else {
    // println "++++++++Else : runTestNG++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
  }
}
```

When I run this test from another task which is setting the property project(':testNG').ext.testJerseyFiles than I get the following

```
++++++++If : runTestNG++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
output/suiteDir/Jersey_setNo1.xml
Running test: test method init(test1.Test1)
```

However the setNo1.xml has a list of a completely different class. It does not seem to pick the file in the "useTestNG" suite option however it is clearly printing out the variable in the "doFirst" closure. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

The more research I do it seems that the suite parameter for the useTestNG is setup at configuration time and since the project.ext.property is being set at execution time it always find the ".hasProperty" to be empty and skips the if clause. Which causes it to go to the test list whatever it finds in the classpath.

Any way to make this suite pick up a list of suite dynamically?